# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (only when certificate managed by Terraform)

Tags: elasticsearch, https, terraform, ssl-certificate, acme

I am trying on an Elasticsearch cluster to set up HTTPS for clients.
It works fine when I generate an SSL certificate from the cluster using certbot via the following command:

```
certbot certonly --standalone
```

My Elasticsearch cluster is configured as follows:

```
# elasticsearch.yml

cluster.initial_master_nodes: 10.132.0.3
cluster.name: elasticsearch
discovery.seed_hosts: 10.132.0.3:9200
network.host: 10.132.0.3
node.name: node-1
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my-subdomain.XXXX.com/fullchain.pem
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/my-subdomain.XXXX.com/privkey.pem
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

I thus manage to authenticate in HTTPS on my elasticsearch using my login and password, via the following command:

```
curl https://my-subdomain.XXXX.com:9200 -u username:password
```

My problem is that I would now like to do the same operation but by generating the SSL certificate via Terraform using the [ACME provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/vancluever/acme/latest/docs)
and more precisely with the [resource "acme_certificate"](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/vancluever/acme/latest/docs/resources/certificate).
Here is my Terraform code:

```
resource "acme_certificate" "elastic" {
  account_key_pem = acme_registration.account_registration.account_key_pem
  common_name = "${local.subdomain}.${var.domain_name}"

  dns_challenge {
    provider = "ovh"

    config = {
      OVH_ENDPOINT = var.ovh_endpoint
      OVH_APPLICATION_KEY = var.ovh_application_key
      OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET = var.ovh_application_secret
      OVH_CONSUMER_KEY = var.ovh_consumer_key
    }
  }
}
```

From Terraform resource "acme_certificate" I get the following outputs:

- "certificate_pem" which will become my "cert.pem" file (but I am not using it in my Elasticsearch setup)
- "issuer_pem"
- "private_key_pem" which will become my "privkey.pem" file

I am therefore missing the "fullchain.pem" file that I build by associating the "certificate_pem" and "issuer_pem" as follows (my error may be there):

```
resource "local_file" "fullchain" {
  content = "${acme_certificate.elastic.certificate_pem}${acme_certificate.elastic.issuer_pem}"
  filename = "/my/local/path/fullchain.pem"
}
```

My "fullchain.pem" file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In the same way as with `cerbot`, I inject my certificate into Elasticsearch with Terraform and verify that the Elastic user has the correct rights (with the `chmod` and `chown` commands)
The elasticsearch service restarts fine, but when I try to connect it gives me the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

I don't understand what the problem is, I have the impression that the certificate returned by Terraform is not correct. But when I test their validity with cerbot, everything seems OK:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in cert.pem       # notAfter=Nov 16 13:55:54 2021 GMT
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in fullchain.pem  # notAfter=Nov 16 13:55:54 2021 GMT
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you include the cert chain in your question please? Note, this shouldn't include the private key and just the intermediate and the issued certificate.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, Do you want me to add the "fullchain.pem" file or the "cert.pem" file?

Comment: Your cert appears to be issued by the staging Let's Encrypt environment. The root CA for this is not in browser/OS trust stores so might be the issue you're seeing there.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you've since edited the question to remove the middle of the certs in the chain. Certs are public by their nature (and since CertificateTransparency you can't even hide the presence of internal resource domain names when a certificate is issued) so you should be able to leave the cert in full in your question to help people debug your certificate issues.

Comment: OK, thanks @ydaetskcoR, I was wondering if this could be sensitive data. I put it back in full

Comment: As long as you don't include the key then it's fine and any user who visited the site would retrieve the certs anyway so they are meant to be public. Prior to Certificate Transparency people would occasionally want to hide the domain names of internal facing resources but Certificate Transparency logs will include this now anyway and anyone seeking to find internal resources on your domain will check those by default rather than hope to find things on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the staging LE server? If so does it still have the issue if you switch to the production LE server?

Comment: I understand your idea, it is true that I went through the Lets'encrypt staging environment to avoid reaching a certain limit at the time of renewal (because I am currently working on a development environment). I will redo the operation via the production environment of LE

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I just tested from the LE production environment. Unfortunately, I have the exact same problem

Comment: Can you update the certificates in the question with the production LE certs please?

Comment: Yes of course. I just updated it.

Comment: I have not found the solution to my problem, but comparing the fullchain.pem files between the Certbot method and the Terraform method, I realize that the 2 are indeed composed of 3 parts :
  - the first part which corresponds to the cert.pem file is different between the 2 methods
  - the second and third part corresponding to the "issuer" are on the other hand perfectly identical